# Cannot remove columns of DataTable before using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I want to remove columns of DataTable that have name start with "##" then bulk to database using C# and SQL Server.

This is my code:

```
private bool WriteData(DataTable _dt)
{
    DataTable dt = _dt.Copy();

    List<string> columnNamesToRemove = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        if (dc.ColumnName.StartsWith("##"))
        {
            columnNamesToRemove.Add(dc.ColumnName);
        }
    }

    foreach (string colName in columnNamesToRemove)
    {
        dt.Columns.Remove(colName);            
    }

    dt.AcceptChanges();     

    if (IsReady())
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);
            conn.Open();
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = Define.TABLE_PREFIX + dt.TableName;
            try
            {
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I has checked data in debug mode and saw columns was removed:

[image]
But when bulking it throws exception:

[image]

And it still create column "##note" in database

[image]

I think I don't know how to modify datatable before bulking as the right way.

Please help me, thanks!

I called

```
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

but nothing changed

Comment: According to the exception message there is a column's type is tinyInt but you pass string

Comment: I understand the message but columns were created in database are columns before I remove column "##note" so data is not matched

Comment: I think your code is for removing data bot column

Comment: @MichaelMao Just to remove note columns

Comment: It seems your data table doesn't match the destination table. Columns are mapped by ordinal if no mapping is specified.

Comment: @DanGuzman It was be ok if I would not remove col by method dt.Columns.Remove

Comment: I think there are some details missing from your question. You said "it still create column "##note" in database". What created the `##note` column? `SqlBulkCopy` does not create columns in the table. If you have columns in the target table that do not exist in the source data table, you need to create a ColumnMappings object with those in the data table you want to load.

Comment: @DanGuzman bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt); will create table and its columns based on DataTable information

Comment: I wasn't aware that `WriteToServer` will create a table. Do you have a documentation reference?

Comment: @DanGuzman I don't see one, you can make a try about it

Comment: I ran a quick test and verified `WriteToServer` does not create the table or columns. The `##NOTE` column wasn't added to the SQL Server table by SqlBulkCopy. You will need to provide the mapping of the data table and target table because the schemas differ in your case.

Comment: @DanGuzman thank you very much! I am missing some additional codes to create table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicit column mapping?

```
using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
{
  //Set the database table name
  sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Customers";
 
  //[OPTIONAL]: Map the DataTable columns with that of the database table
  foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns) {
    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(dc.ColumnName , dc.ColumnName );
  }
    
  con.Open();
  sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
  con.Close();
}
```

Example taken from: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/SqlBulkCopy-Bulk-Copy-data-from-DataTable-DataSet-to-SQL-Server-Table-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Thanks but I want it to be dynamic mapping all columns of DataTable

Comment: OK. I thought you would handle the dynamic mapping from the example. I just updated the answer to use a loop to map each column.

Comment: thank you very much! I am missing some additional codes to create table.

Comment: I think you're missing some conceptual information in your question. You state that you already have a table in your DB. If that's the case, why do you need to create a table from C# code? Are you trying to copy data from one DB table to another? You will have issues trying to do a "CREATE TABLE" statement from C# code because you will have to map all the C# datatypes to SQL datatypes. Perhaps the table creation needs to happen in an SQL stored procedure, not from C#.